# using Call to inherit objects from a function

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, call, apply

I was doing some testing and I got no clue why if using call I inherit from another object like, **const objC = funcB.call(objA,'Erades')** I got an object, but if I inherit from a function I got a function with wired (to me) behavior.

I don't understand why to get method B I have to do **funcC.getLastName()**

If anybody can help me to understand this...

TIA

```js
// testing Call to inherit objects / functions
    // -------------------------------------------
    
    // we declare our first function
    const funcA = function(firstName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.getFirstName = function() {
          return 'My name is ' + this.firstName;
        };
      return this;
    };
    // Create an object out of that function
    const objA = new funcA('Rodrigo');
    
    // declare second function
    const funcB = function (lastName) {
      this.lastName = lastName;
      this.getLastName = function() {
        return 'My last name is ' + this.lastName;
      };
      return this;
    };
    
    // Create an Object from funcB and ObjectA
    const objC = funcB.call(objA,'Erades');
    // We get an object
    console.log("TYPE OF: ", typeof objC)
    console.log('raw:', objC);
    console.log('method A: ', objC.getFirstName());
    console.log('prop A: ', objC.firstName);
    console.log('method B: ', objC.getLastName());
    console.log('prop B: ', objC.lastName);
    console.log('------------');
    
    // if we don't want to create an object out of a function and an object,
    // we could also inherit two functions, but the result really surprise me 
    const funcC = funcB.call(funcA,'Alonso');
    // We get a function !!!!!
    console.log("TYPE OF: ", typeof funcC);
    console.log('raw:', funcC);
    // To get result we need to do this:
    console.log('method ==>: ', funcC('Rui'));
    console.log('method A: ', funcC('Rui').getFirstName());
    console.log('prop A: ', funcC('Maria').firstName);
    console.log('method B: ', funcC.getLastName()); // looks like static method ???
    console.log('prop B: ', funcC.lastName);
    console.log('------------');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not inheriting when you use `call` this way. You are passing an instance in and getting **the same instance** out with some modifications:

```js
const funcA = function(firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.getFirstName = function() {
      return 'My name is ' + this.firstName;
    };
  return this;
};
const objA = new funcA('Rodrigo');

const funcB = function (lastName) {
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.getLastName = function() {
    return 'My last name is ' + this.lastName;
  };
  return this;
};

const objC = funcB.call(objA,'Erades');
// ObjC IS ObjaA
console.log(objC === objA)
```

When you use `call` the object passed in becomes the `this` of the function. You then add some properties and return `this` which is the same object you just passed in.

Passing a function to `call()` is no different. When you write:

```
funcB.call(funcA,'Alonso');
```

you are calling the function `funcB` with `Alonso` as an argument. Inside that function `this` will refer to `funcA`. So you will set a `lastName` property on `funcA` and `getLastName` property pointing to a function, then return `funcA` which is then assigned to the variable `funcC`. *`funcC` and `funcA` point to exactly the same function.*

```js
const funcA = function(firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.getFirstName = function() {
      return 'My name is ' + this.firstName;
    };
  return this;
};

const funcB = function (lastName) {
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.getLastName = function() {
    return 'My last name is ' + this.lastName;
  };
  return this;
};


const funcC = funcB.call(funcA,'Alonso');
// the same reference
console.log(funcC === funcA)
// but when you called funcB with it, it added some properties:
console.log("funC lastname:", funcC.lastName)
// they are the same object so this also works: 
console.log("also funcA lastname:", funcC.lastName)
```

Comment: I see, thanks I had a misconception :), but I stil try to understand the second case when we call a function and pass another function. 

Does function A has a reference to function B ?


If you look at the output of console.log('raw:', funcC) I can't see any reference to function B, but then if I do funcC('Rui')  ---> I can access to function A.

Comment: @Boogie see edited answer. It's not really different with the functions. `funcC` **is** `funcA`